# Different date format in same model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i am doing my project in MVC4 using c#

i have a model

```
         [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:ddd, d MMMM yyyy}")]
          public DateTime Eve_Date { get; set; }
```

that take date from sql database (date is stored in db as mm/dd/yy format with time).My problem is that, I show this date in two view pages, One page shows the date as

Sun, 11 August 2013 (@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Eve_Date))

and another page shows 8/11/2013 12:00:00 AM(@Model.Eve_Date).

In the case of localhost that shown as 31-07-2013 PM 05:00:00(@Model.Eve_Date). But when published the difference is shown. can anybody identify what is the actual problem. i want to show the date in all pages as the format Sun, 11 August 2013

1st page is

```
   @model IEnumerable<....Models.EventDetails>
 <tbody>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<tr><td class="evname"><a href="~/Event/EventDetails/@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Eve_NA)</a></td>
    <td class="evdate">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Eve_Date)</td>
    <td class="evplace">@@@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Eve_Place)</td>
</tr>

}
</tbody>
```

2nd page is

```
  @model P.....Models.EventDetails
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>Event</th><td>@Model.Eve_NA</td><tr>
        <tr><th>Date</th><td>@Model.Eve_Date</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Venue</th><td>@Model.Eve_Place</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Details</th><td><p>@Model.Eve_Desc</p></td></tr>
        <tr><th colspan="2" style="color:#3b619b;">For more information, please contact</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Contact Person</th><td>@Model.Eve_Contact</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Email</th><td>@Model.Eve_Email</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Phone</th><td>@Model.Eve_Phone</td></tr>
   </tbody>
```

Comment: Post your view page code.

Comment: @JeetBhatt: this is my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format in 2 nd page is

```
 @Model.Eve_Date.ToString("ddd, d MMMM yyyy, hh.mm tt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `@Model.Eve_Date` uses the default date format and `DisplayFor` uses the formatting you specified in the `DisplayFormat` attribute.

So you should change the second line to `@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Eve_Date)` as well.

Your system could be set up to show dates in the ddd, d MMMM yyyy formatting. And the server could be using the default US formatting. That's why it's the same on localhost and different on the server.

Comment: first one i work with a loop. second one is a single model. so i cant use item.Eve_date